# Trouble with partial binding updates via knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Code: http://jsbin.com/sarocogamu/edit?html,js,console,output. The model has cats and people eligible to own them. The page itself consists of two `select` elements that allow you to choose a cat, and in the second list, change its owner. For a couple of days I've been looking for ways to cleanly bind objects as values for `select` elements, so I've used a fixed version of code from https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1269#issuecomment-263235814. There is the final issue that is stopping me right now: you can choose a cat, and set its owner alright, but regardless if you *did* change it, choosing a cat will override its owner with the owner chosen in the second list. Example: the second cat is owned by default by Freeman. Choose it right away, and now its owned by Williams, the owner of the first cat. What did I do wrong?

Interestingly, if I make `owner` not an observable, the issue seems to go away, but then the code responsible for making objects usable as binding values breaks. Yukies.

Comment: What's the purpose of your `objectSelect` binding? If you change this binding to a regular `value` binding in the select, it seems to work fine? (http://jsbin.com/qevuwoxoku/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Damn, I couldn't make it work that way, so I assumed it's unsupported, given the docs also imply it: "This function will receive the selected item as its only argument and **should return** a string to use for the <option> element’s value attribute", "If you supply something other than a number or a string (e.g., you pass an object or an array), the displayed text will be equivalent to yourParameter.toString() (that’s usually not very useful, so it’s best to supply string or numeric values).". What sorcery is this?.

Comment: The great thing about knockout's `options` binding, is that your selected value does not need to be a string. By default, knockout will store an actual reference to the object represented by the option. So, if your `value` binding says "Store the selection in `cat().owner`, knockout will forward the selected owner object reference to this observable.